# Consume external API keeping tps in consideration

Tags: spring-boot, tps

I need to call an external API from code, at 10 tps. I have to send multiple requests around ~ 50000. Simply calling in loop may exceed tps resulting in API result failure. Also, simply adding fixed delay in each call will increase overall TAT. I have a function for calling API, but can't find strategy to rate limit function call. When I search related to consuming API using rate limit , all I get is setting rate limit on your API, or how to consume other API...

I think there must be a standard algo in spring boot for this. Any solutions/ references are welcome.